# How to ensure that fineuploader sends a streaming upload request instead of MPE request?

Tags: fine-uploader

I do not see any options to remove parameters or disable sending parameters when uploading using fineuploader. I can only override existing parameters or add new ones. Is there a way to do an upload using PUT without sending any parameters? Since I have signed PUT URI, I don't need to send the parameters. I tried using paramsInBody = false but that adds the content type "octet-stream" to the request. Amazon S3 returns unauthorized because of the incorrect content type.

Note: I am not using fineuploaderS3 since I need to upload to different endpoints.

**Edit**: Additional information

If the upload is not multi-part, fine uploader is adding the following header
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

This causes  an authentication error with amazon S3.

I would like not to send default parameters like qquuid, qqparentsize, qqfile and qqfilename in the body since only file data is expected in the body. Setting paramsInBody to false sends them in query string. This works because the URL parameters are ignored by S3 but I would prefer to have an option to not send them at all.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you don't want Fine Uploader to send any parameters, simply do not set any. "Content-Type" is not a parameter, it is a request header.

Comment: Fineuploader sends a multipart/form-data request for POST. It seems to be doing the same for PUT instead of just sending the file data.

Comment: Please update your question title to reflect that fact that you are trying to ensure Fine Uploader sends a streaming upload request instead of a MPE request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Fine Uploader sends all files as part of a multipart encoded request. To instruct the library to simply send the file as the entire request body, you must set [the `request.forceMultipart` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#request.forceMultipart) to `false`.

Note: It is not possible to prevent uploads sent from IE9 and older to be non-multipart encoded. The *only* way to upload a file in IE9 and older is via a multipart encoded request.

Comment: Using forceMultipart = false adds application/octet-stream header to  content-type. Amazon S3 returns unauthorized because its expects different value for it. For jpeg file, it expects image/jpeg and nothing else in the content type.

Comment: Please [see #1134](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1134). If you require a more specific Content-Type header, you can set this via [the `setCustomHeaders` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#setCustomHeaders).

Comment: I am using the setCustomHeader from onSubmit but fineuploaders adds application/octet-stream to the content-type header after onSubmit has executed. So the request header looks something like "Content-type: image/jpeg, application/octet-stream" when its actually sent.

Comment: That's odd. Apparently calling `XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader` on an already defined header doesn't overwrite the pre-existing value. I wasn't aware of that behavior - it seems a bit non-intuitive. In that case, you'll either need to make the appropriate adjustment described in #1134, or update your code to account for a Content-Type of "application/octet-stream". #1134 will be fixed in the next major version update, since it involves a breaking change.

Comment: It would be preferable if fineuploader does not set the content-type header value at all if its been set from onSubmit. The Content-type value needs to same as the one thats used for creating the S3 signature. I would rather be in control of both values. This way I can set the content-type based on my server's response instead for hoping for fineuploader to use the same content-type value. I have commented out the xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream"); line from fineuploader code as a temporary fix.